# Request Entity Too Large using http client C#

Tags: c#, file, request

Hello something strange happens to me with asp.net. The app is supported to receive up to 51mb and it works fine when receiving file requests, however I am trying to send the same file through an external rest api but there I am getting the error "Request Entity Too Large". The strange thing is that when I send the same file via postman, the destination server accepts the document and responds fine, I only have the problem when sending the file from my application to the external api.

maxRequestLength:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="51200" targetFramework="4.7.2" enableVersionHeader="false" />
```

maxAllowedContentLength:

```
  <security>
     <requestFiltering removeServerHeader="true" >
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="51200" />
      </requestFiltering>
  </security>
```

c# code

```
public async Task Send(ApiRequest request)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        string url = GetUrl();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        var req= new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
        var stream =new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request.base64doc));
        request.base64doc = null;

        StringContent payloadContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var content = new MultipartFormDataContent()
        {
            { new StreamContent(stream), "documentName", request.filename,
            { payloadContent, "data" }
        };

        req.Content = content;

        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(req))
        {
            //gets "request entity too large" 
        }
    }
}
```

my doubt is because the postman lets me send the document and my application does not let me

Do I have to find out when the maximum allowed by the external API is?

Comment: Probably it is the version of http that you are using.  There are versions 1.0, 1.1, 2.0.  Using a sniffer like wireshark you can find version.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I was able to send requests using Postman and not from my application.
The fixture was to update limits on the server side.
Probably request size was bigger when it was sent from the application or nginx was treating requests differently. Unfortunately, I don't have the details regarding server's nginx because it is served by a separate company.